# Combine multiple rows to single row having same values

Tags: mysql

I am working with MYSQL database , and i need to group some Id's which has same value to a single row.For example i am having the table as

```
+-----------+--------+-----------------------------+---------------+
| PROBLEMID | STATUS | EVENTTYPE                   | LOGTIME       |
+-----------+--------+-----------------------------+---------------+
|      3085 | NULL   | ADDED                       | 1397888232903 |
|      2096 | NULL   |ADDED                        | 1397888362183 |
|      3085 | NULL   | NOTES                       | 1397888232904 |
|      3085 | NULL   |SEVERITY                     | 1397888232905 |
+-----------+--------+-----------------------------+---------------+
```

I need to group as 3085 as a single row.

Comment: what about EVENTTYPE when single row?

Comment: i need to combine all data as a single row, so that i can get it in a single query

Comment: i used something like this but still could not get the desired output select * from FilterProblemData p left outer join FilterProblemData pprev on p.PROBLEMID = pprev.PROBLEMID and p.LOGTIME >= pprev.LOGTIME group by p.PROBLEMID, p.LOGTIME

Comment: Please update your question, so we understand what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT PROBLEMID,
       GROUP_CONCAT(EVENTTYPE SEPARATOR ',') AS EVENTTYPE
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY PROBLEMID;
```

For working example [**Click Here**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/496295/2)

Comment: This query worked! But can i include Logtime in GROUP BY clause so as to group EVENTTYPE column based on Logtime.

Comment: If you group by LOGTIME and PROBLEMID then i guess u will have separate rows for each problem

Comment: Yes it worked ! I think there is no need for log time

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY PROBLEMID;
```

Comment: i need the data for all rows when i use select query

Comment: 'I need to group', 'i need the data for all rows'. First decide what do You want. Give more details.

Comment: This actually answers OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select problemid,group_concat(EVENTTYPE) from tname group by problemid;
```

Comment: it's automatically add comma's while con-cat as group.